# TensorFlow Simple audio recognition: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio

TensorFlow: 2.1.0

I am trying to make my own audio classifier using TensorFlow's example, found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio). I'm slowly making my way through the example

I aim for my classifier to be able to detect when someone says a word. Currently I have two labels, one with 15 samples of the word being said slightly differently, the other with 15 samples of noise, each lasting about 1 second. All of these recordings are .wav files

I am up to a point where I keep getting the error

> *tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
> [[{{node Squeeze}}]]*

at this line (121)

```
for waveform, label in waveform_ds.take(1):
    label = label.numpy().decode('utf-8')
    spectrogram = get_spectrogram(waveform)
```

printing waveform_ds yields:
*<ParallelMapDataset shapes: ((None,), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.string)>*

I'm unsure what to do at this stage, any nudges in the right direction as to how I can fix this are appreciated. Full code is shown below.

```
import os
import pathlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
from IPython import display

def decode_audio(audio_binary):
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary)
    return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)

def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)

    # Note: You'll use indexing here instead of tuple unpacking to enable this 
    # to work in a TensorFlow graph.
    return parts[-2]

def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
    return waveform, label


def get_spectrogram(waveform):
    # Padding for files with less than 16000 samples
    zero_padding = tf.zeros([16000] - tf.shape(waveform), dtype=tf.float32)

    # Concatenate audio with padding so that all audio clips will be of the 
    # same length
    waveform = tf.cast(waveform, tf.float32)
    equal_length = tf.concat([waveform, zero_padding], 0)
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(
      equal_length, frame_length=255, frame_step=128)

    spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)

    return spectrogram

def plot_spectrogram(spectrogram, ax):
    # Convert to frequencies to log scale and transpose so that the time is
    # represented in the x-axis (columns).
    log_spec = np.log(spectrogram.T)
    height = log_spec.shape[0]
    X = np.arange(16000, step=height + 1)
    Y = range(height)
    ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, log_spec)
    
def get_spectrogram_and_label_id(audio, label):
    spectrogram = get_spectrogram(audio)
    spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, -1)
    label_id = tf.argmax(label == commands)
    return spectrogram, label_id

def preprocess_dataset(files):
    files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
    output_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    output_ds = output_ds.map(
      get_spectrogram_and_label_id,  num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    return output_ds

# Set seed for experiment reproducibility
seed = 42
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

data_dir = pathlib.Path('D:\\WordAudioAI\\training_data') # have two folders inside this directory: noise and the word

commands = np.array(tf.io.gfile.listdir(str(data_dir)))
commands = commands[commands != 'README.md']
print('Commands:', commands)

filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(str(data_dir) + '/*/*')
filenames = tf.random.shuffle(filenames)
num_samples = len(filenames)
print('Number of total examples:', num_samples)
print('Number of examples per label:', len(tf.io.gfile.listdir(str(data_dir/commands[0]))))
print('Example file tensor:', filenames[0])

# Split the files into training, validation and test sets using a 80:10:10 ratio, respectively.

train_ratio = int(len(filenames)*0.8)
val_ratio = int(len(filenames)*0.1)

train_files = filenames[:train_ratio]
val_files = filenames[train_ratio: train_ratio + val_ratio]
test_files = filenames[-val_ratio:]

print('Training set size', len(train_files))
print('Validation set size', len(val_files))
print('Test set size', len(test_files))

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
waveform_ds = files_ds.map(get_waveform_and_label, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

# Let's examine a few audio waveforms with their corresponding labels

#rows = 3
#cols = 3
#n = rows*cols
#fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10, 12))
#for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(waveform_ds.take(n)):
    #r = i // cols
    #c = i % cols
    #ax = axes[r][c]
    #ax.plot(audio.numpy())
    #ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-1.2, 1.2, 0.2))
    #label = label.numpy().decode('utf-8')
    #ax.set_title(label)

#plt.show()

# ***PROBLEM AREA***
print(waveform_ds)
for waveform, label in waveform_ds.take(1):
    label = label.numpy().decode('utf-8')
    spectrogram = get_spectrogram(waveform)

print('Label:', label)
print('Waveform shape:', waveform.shape)
print('Spectrogram shape:', spectrogram.shape)
print('Audio playback')
display.display(display.Audio(waveform, rate=16000))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(12, 8))
timescale = np.arange(waveform.shape[0])
axes[0].plot(timescale, waveform.numpy())
axes[0].set_title('Waveform')
axes[0].set_xlim([0, 16000])
plot_spectrogram(spectrogram.numpy(), axes[1])
axes[1].set_title('Spectrogram')
plt.show()

spectrogram_ds = waveform_ds.map(
    get_spectrogram_and_label_id, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

# Examine the spectrogram "images" for different samples of the dataset.

#rows = 3
#cols = 3
#n = rows*cols
#fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10, 10))
#for i, (spectrogram, label_id) in enumerate(spectrogram_ds.take(n)):
    #r = i // cols
    #c = i % cols
    #ax = axes[r][c]
    #plot_spectrogram(np.squeeze(spectrogram.numpy()), ax)
    #ax.set_title(commands[label_id.numpy()])
    #ax.axis('off')

#plt.show()

train_ds = spectrogram_ds
val_ds = preprocess_dataset(val_files)
test_ds = preprocess_dataset(test_files)

#batch_size = 64
#train_ds = train_ds.batch(batch_size)
#val_ds = val_ds.batch(batch_size)

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(AUTOTUNE)

for spectrogram, _ in spectrogram_ds.take(1):
    input_shape = spectrogram.shape
print('Input shape:', input_shape)
num_labels = len(commands)

norm_layer = preprocessing.Normalization()
norm_layer.adapt(spectrogram_ds.map(lambda x, _: x))

model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
    preprocessing.Resizing(32, 32), 
    norm_layer,
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Dropout(0.25),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(num_labels),
])

model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

EPOCHS = 10
history = model.fit(
    train_ds, 
    validation_data=val_ds,  
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(verbose=1, patience=2),
)

metrics = history.history
plt.plot(history.epoch, metrics['loss'], metrics['val_loss'])
plt.legend(['loss', 'val_loss'])
plt.show()

test_audio = []
test_labels = []

for audio, label in test_ds:
    test_audio.append(audio.numpy())
    test_labels.append(label.numpy())

test_audio = np.array(test_audio)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(test_audio), axis=1)
y_true = test_labels

test_acc = sum(y_pred == y_true) / len(y_true)
print(f'Test set accuracy: {test_acc:.0%}')

confusion_mtx = tf.math.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred) 
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
sns.heatmap(confusion_mtx, xticklabels=commands, yticklabels=commands, annot=True, fmt='g')
plt.xlabel('Prediction')
plt.ylabel('Label')
plt.show()

sample_file = data_dir/'no/01bb6a2a_nohash_0.wav'

sample_ds = preprocess_dataset([str(sample_file)])

for spectrogram, label in sample_ds.batch(1):
    prediction = model(spectrogram)
    plt.bar(commands, tf.nn.softmax(prediction[0]))
    plt.title(f'Predictions for "{commands[label[0]]}"')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding `desired_channels=1` like this:

```
def decode_audio(audio_binary):
    audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary, desired_channels=1,) 
    return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

After investigating I found tt's because my .wav files were duel channel instead of mono.

If someone knows of an easier or better way to train an audio classifier, please let me know :)